# How to exclude a class from Spring in applicationContext?

Tags: java, spring

Here we only want to exclude a class from certain classpath, say

`com.abc.projectA.service.orderService.sectionA.orderService.class`

However there is another class with same name but in different classpath

`com.abc.projectA.service.orderService.sectionB.orderService.class`

so that only filer by class name is not going to work.

But I tried the following method:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc">
    <!--other filters-->
    <!--.......-->
    <context:exclude-filter expression="projectA\.service\.orderService\.sectionA\.orderService" type="regex" />
</context:component-scan>
```

It doesn't work. So I bet the `<context:exclude-filter>` only valid on package level but not for specific class? If so, how to exclude a class from bean injection so that we can pick and choose with class to get wired with same class name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, the exclude should work, the issue that you are having is probably that you are assuming that the path in regex will be pre-pended with the base-package which is not true..so just specify the full package

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc">
    <!--other filters-->
    <!--.......-->
    <context:exclude-filter expression="com\.abc\.projectA\.service\.orderService\.sectionA\.orderService" type="regex" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Thanks. What if in real case we actually want to exclude an aspect(not expression, but aspect.aj and aspact.class) how can we achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting beans you should be including the full package location of classes so that classes with duplicate names are never a problem. For instance:

```
<bean id="orderServiceA" class="com.foo.bar.a.OrderService">

<bean id="orderServiceB" class="com.foo.barr.b.OrderService">
```

Now you can have both and not run into any issues. Maybe I am missing something, but I do not understand why you need to eliminate a class because it has the same name as another class in a different package. I mean the Java SDK has multiple classes called List and it never causes an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but because by default Spring will identify the bean by name instead of id and in real case we actually want to exclude an aspect instead of a regular class so may not use id to identify the bean.

Comment: Then provide the beans with a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are trying to break the Unique Package Names convention described in the [Java Spec: section 7.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/packages.html#7.7).

Or are you trying to load different versions of the same classes? Your classloader may not be able to disambiguate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes it is not good practice and it is kind of a specific case.